# How to change a quantifier in a Regex based on a condition?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to find words of length >= 1 which may contain a `'` or a `-` within. Here is a test string:

`a quake-prone area- (aujourd'hui-`

In Python, I'm currently using this regex:

```
string = "a quake-prone area- (aujourd'hui-"
RE_WORDS = re.compile(r'[a-z]+[-\']?[a-z]+')
words = RE_WORDS.findall(string)
```

I would like to get this result:

```
>>> words
>>> [u'a', u'quake-prone', u'area', u"aujourd'hui"]
```

but I get this instead:

```
>>> words
>>> [u'quake-prone', u'area', u"aujourd'hui"]
```

Unfortunately, because of the last `+` quantifier, it skips all words of length 1. If I use the `*` quantifier, it will find `a` but also `area-` instead of `area`.

Then how could create a conditional regex saying: `if the word contains an apostrophe or an hyphen, use the + quantifier else use the * quantifier` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change the last `[-\']?[a-z]+` part as optional by putting it into a group and then adding a `?` quantifier next to that group.

```
>>> string = "a quake-prone area- (aujourd'hui-"
>>> RE_WORDS = re.compile(r'[a-z]+(?:[-\'][a-z]+)?')
>>> RE_WORDS.findall(string)
['a', 'quake-prone', 'area', "aujourd'hui"]
```

Reason for why the `a` is not printed is because of your regex contains two `[a-z]+` which asserts that there must be atleast two lowercase letters present in the match.

Note that the regex i mentioned won't match `area-` because `(?:[-\'][a-z]+)?` optional group asserts that there must be atleast one lowercase letter would present just after to the `-` symbol. If no, then stop matching until it reaches the hyphen. So that you got `area` at the output instead of `area-` because there isn't an lowercase letter exists next to the `-`.  Here it  stops matching until it finds an hyphen without following lowercase letter.

Comment: @Avinash_Raf That was very smart! I'm still a beginner regarding regexes so I will spend some time thinking about your answer and might come back at you if I have some further questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems the `?` after `[-\']` is not necessary anymore. What do you think ? edit: damn I was thinking so much about this regex I forgot to accept your answer... Fixed :)